# Access database table keeps getting chinese characters where they don't belong

Tags: database, ms-access

**EDIT**  This is not a duplicate, as I do not have any Memo fields.  I am also not grouping anything.  The corruption is always found within the Prime table.

Lately, I am often getting a single line of data in my access 2010 db coming up with a load of chinese characters.  It has happened before, but lately it is becoming a regular occurrence and I would very much like it to stop.
Here is what I have going on and what limitations I have.

Access split database.  Multiple users.  Users only have an *.accdr front end to work in, stored locally on their desktops (only about 6 users in total).  They all use the access 2010 runtime, very very few have full MS access on their machines.

The Backend is stored on a large shared sitewide drive (or series of drives) that on all users machines is simply "G:"  This drive, it should be noted, occasionally has issues like being too full.  I have no means to put the backend on a dedicated machine, and other software is out of the question.  IT support is offsite, and frankly they are about as clued in as AOL tech support was in the 90's.

Normal daily procedure is to load the output from another program into a merge table.  This merge table is kept so we can spot changes and duplication. The merge table is then appended into the Prime table.  Primary key in the Prime table prevents over writing existing information.  The primary key is on 5 different columns in the prime table.  Each column may have legitimate repeating values, but the combination of those values is unique.  I have no pre-defined relationships.  all relationships are shown on the query level. A backup of the data in the Prime table is done by creating an excel file once per day.  I run Compact and Repair on the database every couple of weeks.

Every once in a long while, some hiccup in the universe, or data collision, or strange hard drive problem would cause a line in the Prime table to turn into chinese characters.  When that happens, I check the backup excel file to make sure the corruption is not there.  I then have everyone get out of the database.  I run a Compact and repair,  remove the offending line, C&R again, and get on with my day.  This used to happen maybe once every 2 months.

Now I am getting this corruption on what seems to be an accelerating cycle.  Once a week, 3 times a week, now it seems to be daily.

The changes in the front end made recently have all been form level stuff.  Not anything in the queries themselves.

My boss won't accept the "Unusual sunspot and solar flare activity" excuse anymore.

What should I do to prevent this (within my limitations)?

Thanks in advance folks.

**EDIT 2**
The last few days we have been trying to systematically test various things to reproduce and isolate the corruption. I have an additional person who normally runs the daily update per my instructions.  We reviewed the process and no problems or deviation.  I have access to 4 different machines I can run the updates on so day one we used my daily use computer (Access 2013).  Step by step checking for corruption.  No corruption.  Day 2 was on a machine that only has Access 2010, with same step by step process checks.  No Corruption.  Day 3 will be on my co-workers machine with the same step by step checks.  I'll update as I go.  I wonder if the problem could be machine specific.

Comment: How many rows in the table? How large is the actual database file?

Comment: The Prime table is around 40,000 rows.  The merge table is usually around 15,000 rows.  Merge is cleared daily and reloaded with the daily output from a different program.  Total size of the backend is around 90MB(after C&R).  Prime table is around 150 columns (I know, but that's how the crap comes out of the other program).

Comment: None of the fields are being grouped.  The corrupted line is always in the prime table, So when I found the other question, it didn't fit.

Comment: You really should move the data to Sql Server Express (free). -- Apart from that, I can only suggest: run the import + merge at a fixed time each day. Every other user must quit the database at this time. After import+merge as single user, run Compact&Repair straight away (every day!). Then everyone else can get back in.

Comment: @Andre Sadly, software changes have to be approved by the IT support team, from another country, and by people who are....less than helpful.  So SQL server is a battle lost before it even begins.  The import and merge are run at the same time everyday, before users even get here.  I have heard that running a C&R daily can cause problems as well.  That's why I do it regularly, but haven't been doing it daily.

Comment: *I have heard that running a C&R daily can cause problems as well.* -- I think that's a myth. Making a copy of the data db before running C&R is always a good idea, though.

Comment: *"The Backend is stored on a large shared sitewide drive (or series of drives) that on all users machines is simply 'G:'"* - Can you confirm that the network share mapped as "G:" is on a real Windows server (as opposed to a network appliance running SAMBA on Linux or some other non-Microsoft implementation of SMB/CIFS)?

Comment: @GordThompson sadly no.  I suspect it's a Windows server, but that is based more on the company's habit of buying off the rack solutions than any sort of verifiable information.

Comment: @Andre Edited to explain what we are doing to take care of the problem. What do ya think?

Comment: @GordThompson  Edited to explain what we are doing to take care of the problem. What do ya think?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some careful testing, incorporating advice in all of the comments, we f determined that the problem most likely rests with the fact that the drive the DB resides in was getting full.  The problem started when the drive was approaching about 90% of capacity.  Since then, the Drive has been somewhat cleaned of old files, the drive is now at about 60% of capacity, and the corruption problems have gone away.  We'll keep monitoring.
Thanks again for all the advice, and I hope this helps others in the future!